# Initiation Form Error - Length of property is limited

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, office-365, initiation-form

I am really hoping that someone here either has run into this issue, or has a suggestion for me.

I created a workflow to simply create a link to a document in a separate list when it is uploaded into the document library. I originally had the workflow running automatically when an item is created or modified.

It worked for months, but here recently we started getting errors:

> Item xxxxxxxx (current item name) was modified by xxxxx@xxxxx.com (always the current user) at date/time

This happened every time someone tried to make a change, including adding the properties after the document was uploaded.

I am not sure what happened that made this happen, I tried adding a 2 minute pause to the workflow to see if that corrected the issue, and it did for the first two documents, then I started getting the errors again so I figured I would try running it manually instead of automatically.

I do not want to add more steps to this process, but the user needs to fill out a few properties about the document first so I wanted to use the Initiation Form to gather this information. The problem I run into is that two of the properties are large drop-down menus, and when I try to publish the Workflow I get the following:

> Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were not saved.

When I click the Advanced button I get:

> The length of the property is limited to 10000 characters.

I can publish the workflow if I remove the two large drop-downs from the initiation form, but I have to have that information. Is there a way to up the property length limit or another workaround? We are using SharePoint Online.